# VBA: More than 30 arguments in the method Application.Union(.......)

Tags: excel, vba, arguments, union, multipleselection

in my VBA-Code I'm selecting multiple cells with the method Application.Union(....)

See the code below

```
        Union(Range(Cells(1, spalte11), Cells(2, spalte11)), Range(Cells(txtBoxRangeAValue + 2, spalte11), Cells(txtBoxRangeBValue + 2, spalte11)), _
          Range(Cells(1, spalte12), Cells(2, spalte12)), Range(Cells(txtBoxRangeAValue + 2, spalte12), Cells(txtBoxRangeBValue + 2, spalte12)), _
          Range(Cells(1, spalte13), Cells(2, spalte13)), Range(Cells(txtBoxRangeAValue + 2, spalte13), Cells(txtBoxRangeBValue + 2, spalte13)), _
          Range(Cells(1, spalte14), Cells(2, spalte14)), Range(Cells(txtBoxRangeAValue + 2, spalte14), Cells(txtBoxRangeBValue + 2, spalte14)), _
          Range(Cells(1, spalte15), Cells(2, spalte15)), Range(Cells(txtBoxRangeAValue + 2, spalte15), Cells(txtBoxRangeBValue + 2, spalte15)), _
          Range(Cells(1, spalte16), Cells(2, spalte16)), Range(Cells(txtBoxRangeAValue + 2, spalte16), Cells(txtBoxRangeBValue + 2, spalte16)), _
          Range(Cells(1, spalte17), Cells(2, spalte17)), Range(Cells(txtBoxRangeAValue + 2, spalte17), Cells(txtBoxRangeBValue + 2, spalte17)), _
          Range(Cells(1, spalte18), Cells(2, spalte18)), Range(Cells(txtBoxRangeAValue + 2, spalte18), Cells(txtBoxRangeBValue + 2, spalte18)), _
          Range(Cells(1, spalte21), Cells(2, spalte21)), Range(Cells(txtBoxRangeAValue + 2, spalte21), Cells(txtBoxRangeBValue + 2, spalte21)), _
          Range(Cells(1, spalte22), Cells(2, spalte22)), Range(Cells(txtBoxRangeAValue + 2, spalte22), Cells(txtBoxRangeBValue + 2, spalte22)), _
          Range(Cells(1, spalte23), Cells(2, spalte23)), Range(Cells(txtBoxRangeAValue + 2, spalte23), Cells(txtBoxRangeBValue + 2, spalte23)), _
          Range(Cells(1, spalte24), Cells(2, spalte24)), Range(Cells(txtBoxRangeAValue + 2, spalte24), Cells(txtBoxRangeBValue + 2, spalte24)), _
          Range(Cells(1, spalte25), Cells(2, spalte25)), Range(Cells(txtBoxRangeAValue + 2, spalte25), Cells(txtBoxRangeBValue + 2, spalte25)), _
          Range(Cells(1, spalte26), Cells(2, spalte26)), Range(Cells(txtBoxRangeAValue + 2, spalte26), Cells(txtBoxRangeBValue + 2, spalte26)), _
          Range(Cells(1, spalte27), Cells(2, spalte27)), Range(Cells(txtBoxRangeAValue + 2, spalte27), Cells(txtBoxRangeBValue + 2, spalte27))).Select
```

Above I'm selecting all the 30 arguments allowed in the method Application.Union(...)+

But actually I would like to select more than 30 Ranges.

Is that possible?

Comment: Make an array of all the `spalte` then loop that using Union to add them one at a time.

Comment: If you explain the purpose of what you're trying to achieve, maybe there is another solution

Answer (score 0):

> Define a vector containing the strings of each range

```
Dim v() As Variant
ReDim v(n) 'n is number of your desired ranges, more than 30 arguments allowable by a simple Union
For i = 0 To n - 1
    'v(i) = '.... is a string which is the address of each range
Next i
```

> Define a range RR upon which you add ranges incrementally using Union

```
Dim RR As Range
For i = 0 To n
    If i = 0 Then
        Set RR = Range(v(i))
    Else
        Set RR = Union(RR, Range(v(i)))
    End If
Next i
RR.Select
```

Comment: Vector? Do you mean Variant?